# Move file in Drupal 6

Tags: 7, files

I am using drupal 6 as i am trying to save file that comes from another server through Json format

I am using

```
file_move('path of image','sites/default/files');
```

I also tried this  one Still having same error

```
file_move('path of image','sites/default/files', $replace = FILE_EXISTS_RENAME));
```

But it gives this error

> Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in

How to solve this? Anybody have idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your First argument must be a variable. The `file_move()` documentation says:

> `$source`: Either a string specifying the file location of the original file or an object containing a 'filepath' property. This parameter is passed by reference and will contain the resulting destination filename in case of success.

Comment: Now i got this error 

he selected file could not be copied, because no file by that name exists. Please check that you supplied the correct filename.
Can you tell me how to solve this please